# Loop for checking string change in system function output (monitoring a DNS update)

Tags: ruby, monitoring

I am switching DNS servers and I'd like to write a short ruby script that runs every 10s and triggers a local Mac OS X system notification as soon as my website resolves to a different IP.

Using [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier) sending a system notification is as easy as this

```
terminal-notifier -message "DNS Changed"
```

I'd like to trigger it as soon as the output of

```
ping -i 10 mywebsite.com
```

... changes or simply does not contain a defined IP string anymore.

```
> 64 bytes from 12.34.56.789: icmp_seq=33 ttl=41 time=241.564 ms
```

in this case "12.34.56.789".

- How do I monitor the change of the output string of the *ping -i 10 mywebsite.com* and call the notification function once a change has been detected?

I thought this might be a nice practice while waiting for the DNS to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IP = "12.34.56.789"
p = IO.popen("ping -i 10 mywebsite.com")
p.each_line do |l|
  if(! l =~ /from #{IP}/) #The IP has changed
    system("terminal-notifier -message \"DNS Changed\"")
  end
end
```

Comment: You should know that `ping` only resolves the IP address at start and does not re-resolve it for each ping sent. This means that the IP in that string will never change. You could still write very similar code to yours but include the ping `popen` in the loop and pass in the arguments `-c 1` to ping so it only sends a single ping before quitting.